# stancl/tenancy Custom Database Name

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using laravel version 6 and also using **stancl/tenancy** package for dynamic database, but now I have some problem when I type this command "php artisan tenants:create -d my-domain1.com name=my-domain-1 plan=free email=foo@test.local othes=test" to create a new database I got database name like this "ecommerce_db_af0a82cc-aa3f-48dc-8ded-3b70c4ba833b" so I want to custom database name by my own I try to read the documentation of that package but can't understand you can see my [database name that I have generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIM0c.png)

Comment: the documentation of that package doesn't have the example so I really hard to understand if you know about this, please

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that helps:

Change the config/tenancy.php with it:

```
'prefix' => 'tenant_',
```

Change your command file with it:

```
protected $signature = 'tenants:create {tenant?}';
```

and the handle:

```
if ($this->argument('tenant')) {

        $this->info("Creating Tenant #{$this->argument('tenant')}#")

        $tenant = Tenant::create([
            'id' => "{$this->argument('tenant')}",
        ]);

    }
```